# Firefox The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, google-chrome

When I go to a particular url on my [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) site I get this error in Firefox.  The page in question is a login screen.

The page isn't redirecting properly

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept cookies.

Chrome says

> This web page has a redirect loop The web page at  has resulted
>   in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing
>   third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a
>   server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

```
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
Learn more about this problem.
```

Why might this be happening?  After reloading a couple of times the problem does go away.

Comment: Like the browsers say: your code keeps redirecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Fiddler [(download)](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and look at requests, you will find some count of HTTP redirects, then browser will stop and show such messages. You need debug your application, maybe this is some cross redirects, custom return url logic or anything else, without code it's hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks , i used `firebug`and saw 21 request loops in Net Tab,  my mistake was i did `return RedirectToAction("Login");` in same Login `ActionMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, Login.aspx page was redirecting to default page ~/. Solution was hard to find, but going deeper revealed that IIS server has from some version set Login.aspx as default page. Hence there was indefinite loop in redirecting, the removal od Login.aspx from default pages (Default Document) in IIS GUI(!) solved the problem. Hope this helps somebody. Just changing config files was not enough, the GUI approach worked well.