# how to validate the session in spring mvc interceptor

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, interceptor

I am newbie to spring framework.In my code,i use the interceptor for checking the session exists or not.If session exists i allow to call the controller otherwise i redirect the login page.
Below is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,



        Users user=(Users) session.getAttribute("user");
        if(user == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Request Path : ");
            response.sendRedirect("index");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but this code not redirect successfully.I am getting the below error,

```
In Mozilla i get below error
    The page is not redirecting properly
In chorme i get below error?
    This web page has redirect loop
```

How to fix this issue?Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Which browser do you test? According to my readings at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397105/firefox-the-page-isnt-redirecting-properly and https://support.mozilla.org/tr/questions/985967. You first need to understand what is your exact problem. If you use Mozilla you can use tamper data to track your site redirection. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

Comment: i use mozilla firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wild guess, because you forgot to say how your interceptor is configured. I think it could be caused by the interceptor being applied to the login page `index`.

If this is true any page will ask the browser to redirect to `index` page, but `index` page itself will send a redirect request to browser.

The correct way is to configure the interceptor to ignore the login page

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,

        // ignore login page
        if (request.getServletPath() == "/index") { // BEWARE : to be adapted to your actual login page
            return true;
        }

        Users user=(Users) session.getAttribute("user");
        if(user == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Request Path : ");
            response.sendRedirect("index");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

You could also use SpringMVC configuration to have the interceptor not applied to the login page

But anyway, if you want to build a serious application, my advice is to have a look to [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) that nicely integrates in a Spring MVC application and comes with a bunch of examples to avoid above problem (and others ...)