# interceptor prehandle not redirecting to login page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, interceptor

if the user login in ie browser and after login its redirect to `index.jsp` so copy this url and paste to another browser chrome so in this time it redirect to login page to prevent direct access to `index.jsp`. 
I introduced a `sessionInterceptor` to prevent direct access to `index.jsp` (should be redirected to `login.html`). The code is hitting the `preHandle()` method and running all the code but after return `false` it's not redirecting to `login.html`. What's wrong?

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);



    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        if (session.getAttribute("isUserLoggedIn") == null) {
         response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.html");
         return false;
        }

        System.out.println(request.getSession() + "--Before Method ");
        System.out.println("---Before Method Execution---");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(request.getSession()+ "---post Method ");
        System.out.println("---post Method Execution---");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(request.getSession() + "---after Method ");
        System.out.println("---after Method Execution---");

    }

}
```

Comment: Judging from the code you posted you are probably caught in a redirect loop... The attribute is still `null` and you will redirect, in which it still is `null` and redirect etc. etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum i am not getting your point..  when user geting logged first time i set the session.setAttribute("isUserLoggedIn", "isUserLoggedIn");
And then this time this attribute is not null.
Now index.jsp page will open and after that if user will copy of the URL of this page and paste it on the other browse (chrome to IE)so this time it will go to interceptor preHandle() and session.getAttribute("isUserLoggedIn") == null now the page will redirect on login page.

Comment: Which is again protected by this interceptor (I assume) unless that is a page not mapped by a controller in spring MVC.

Comment: @M.Deinum i think u told i am doing this way

@RequestMapping(value = {"/login "}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String notLogged() {
     return "login";
 }
but this also not work to redirect my page

Comment: It won't as it is protected as well... You should exclude some urls from being protected.. (Although I would actually suggest you would use Spring Security instead of inventing your own security framework).

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598757/how-to-validate-the-session-in-spring-mvc-interceptor

Comment: @Narayana Ganesh but its not redirected to any jsp page ,If i redirect it to the link http://www.google.com/ it open the google page but if i redirect it to the any jsp page it gives 404 error